# CSS problems on android device

Tags: css, webkit

I have a pretty simple navbar, which has it's background defined by using CSS's, background-image property with the linear-gradient function. It works great in every latest desktop browser, and it also works in Android 4.4+ browsers too. But when I am testing it on a 4.4- Android device, the backround is not visible. I've checked **caniuse.com** which says the following things:

> that background-image property works only partially on Android 4.3- (size is not supported which I am not using anyways)
>
> that linear-gradient function on Android 4.3- works only with the -webkit- prefix

So this would be my problem, I tought, and tried to implement a webkit version of the same css property, but to no avail. I can't make this work, what could I be doing wrong? Here's the css rule that I am using, and below it, you will find some additions that I have tried, but without success. The background appears correctly on desktop browsers, but it is invisible on mobile devices(tested it with a physical Galaxy Express, with 4.2 Android, and with a bunch of other 4.3- Androids on BrowserStack).

```
.converser_navbar {
  height: 50px; 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #6374B6 0px, #3D538C 100%); 
  /* this is the webkit version, tried putting it after and before the non webkit version, 
  neither one works, also tried using ONLY the webkit version, that only disables the 
  background on the desktop browsers too, also tried prefixing background-image 
  with -webkit-, but that also does nothing at all */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6374B6 0px, #3D538C 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #898989;
  color: #FFF; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 10;
  top:0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: maybe  -webkit-gradient?

Comment: background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #6374B6 0px, #3D538C 100%);  top instead bottom